# How to maintain div wrapper aspect ratio?

Tags: css, html

I am having an issue with my divs moving when the page is resized.  If you look at the plunker you will see a Header with boxes below. If you resize the workspace by dragging the scroll bar to the left you will see how the page should be.  I tried wrapping all items in 1 div named wrapper and tried both relative and absolute positioning with a min-width.  I also did the same for body.  After inspecting the page with firebug looks like the html tag should have sizing or positioning.  That didn't work either (see below).  I would like to be able to minimize my screen to 50% and maximize to 250% and keep the same initial layout as if my screen is at 95% based on the wrapper.  Any ideas?

Here's [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Vf6BIFCRLt6K99seK09?p=preview)

```
<html>
body, html{margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%; min-width: 900px; position:relative}

div.wrapper{ width:95%; min-width: 900px; padding-left: 6px; padding-top:5px; position: relative;  }

<body>
 <div class="wrapper" >
   <div id="header">
     <img  align="left" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px; width: 80px; height: 65px"><h1> Header</h1>
  </div>

 <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>

 </div> <!--end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you use min-width?

Comment: use fluid (`%` or `em`' s or `vw`) `width`s over fixed `width`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use percentage and fix min-wheight + set overflow to auto (looks like frameset .. not so nice actually)

Or you could try to relay on `box-sizing` and use vertical `padding` on percentage value(it will use parent's `width` as reference).

floatting pseudo can then, be used and will allow divs to grow taller instead showing a scrollbar.

```css
. {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width:1300px;
  margin:auto; /* ?*/
}
.wrapper #header ~ div {
  border:double;
  margin:0.4% 0.2%;
  padding:5px;
}
#header, .right, .rightbottom {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
  float:left;
  width:30%;
}
.left:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  padding-top:204.5%;
}
.right:before, .rightbottom:before {
  content:'';
  padding-top:30%;
  float:left;
}
.wrapper #header ~ div.rightbottom {
  border:solid 1px;
}
.rightbottom:before {
  padding-top:60%;
}
```

```html
 
<div class="wrapper" >

<div id="header">
  <img  align="left" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px; width: 80px; height: 65px"><h1> Header</h1>
</div>
    
      <div class="left">
      
     </div>
    

         <div class="right" >
        
     
        <div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions1">grid</div>
      
           
         </div>
        
        <div class="rightbottom">right bottom</div>
                    
       
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/K1yOpBOfX3ukqHX7f2oa?p=preview

I'm not too sure of what kind of behavior you look for once there is real stuff in your pages.

Comment: Thanks GCyrillus.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the header and the two divs to always have their own row, perhaps you could contain them each in divs that are set to `width: 100%`?